# Pass Universal Encoding from JSP to backing bean

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, encoding

Currently I'm using Eclipse to develop a JAVA Dynamic web project, and I want to use JSP to submit some universal characters(e.g. Japanese/Chinese) to my backing bean and then to the database. I have been searching for several solutions online, but unfortunately none of them work for me. (FYI, displaying the characters are functioning well)

- I have done with the changes in the webpage headings:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
  ```
- I have done with changes in the web.xml:

  ```
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
  ```
- In the persistence.xml, I've done with the changes:

  ```
  property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
  ```
- In tomcat server.xml, I've done with the changes:

  ```
  URIEncoding="UTF-8"
  ```
- For bean properties and database column, I've also set them to be utf-8 and which have been tested to be working.

All these changes don't actually solve the problem. From the JSP I typed like "哈" in my `<h:inputText>`, and it turns out to be showing "& # 2 1 7 0 4 ;"(which I believe to be the actual utf code of the character) in my backing bean as well as appear in database.

I've also seen some other methods like forcing such as `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8")`, however since I'm directly link the JSP to backing bean, so this one doesn't apply to my case.

Comment: I don't understand your problem at all. It can be resumed as "From the JSP I typed `"some japanese character"`, and it turns out to appear as `"the same japanese character"` in the backing bean and in the database. So what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Hi, My problem is that when I type foreign language in the JSP, it turns out to be the utf-code ("& # 2 1 7 0 4 ;") inside backing bean and database.
Sorry, in the question the browser automatically converted the code to the correct character.

Comment: Your problem can't be solved until you post an example of what is not working, this means not understandable question.

Comment: Sorry for the complex scenario description.
1. From JSP, I typed "哈哈" in the h:inputText field,
2. In the backing bean, I use print to get received values, which shows: pass name: [&_#_2_1_7_0_4_; &_#_2_1_7_0_4_;], this value is the unicode(ascii?) for the characters that I passed from JSP,
3. This value is directly inserted into my database, and without converted back to the original chinese values that I typed in the JSP page.
Is it clearer to help you understand the problem?

Thanks again!!!

Comment: Can your database actually store the character as itself rather than the escaped unicode sequence?

Comment: Hi, yes my database does support the utf. I manually add the special characters to the input string in my backing bean before submitting to database(eg. input = input+"哈哈"), and it goes in as expected. So in the database I will get &_#_2_1_7_0_4_; &_#_2_1_7_0_4_;哈哈.